# Who are the giants in Isaiah 14

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In [Isaiah 14:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.14.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says: "Gehinnom from beneath quaked for you, toward your arrival; it aroused for you the giants, all the chiefs of the earth; it caused all the kings of the nations to rise from their thrones."

Are these the giants from Genesis?

Comment: According to some commentaries it is just a reference to the dead.

Comment: [Raphaite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rephaite) .. [רפאים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D)

Comment: "Giants" is just one translation (and might be linked to the word refa'im or Atudei Aretz).  There are other translations that avoid the word "giants" entirely.